# LoadScene screwing up moving objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I launch a level from the menu, the moving objects decide to suddenly teleport to their next location. I don't have this problem if I launch it from the level rather than the menu.

I followed this tutorial to get this code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rO19dA2jksk

> Moving platforms:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3[] points;
    public int pointNumber = 0;
    private Vector3 currentTarget;

    public float tolerance;
    public float speed;
    public float delayTime;

    private float delayStart;

    public bool automatic;

    void Start ()
    {
        if(points.Length > 0) 
        {
            currentTarget = points[0];
        }
        tolerance = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if (transform.position != currentTarget)
        {
            MovePlatform();
        } 
        else
        {
            UpdateTarget();
        }
    }

    void MovePlatform() 
    {
        Vector3 heading = currentTarget - transform.position;
        transform.position += (heading / heading.magnitude) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (heading.magnitude < tolerance)
        {
            transform.position = currentTarget;
            delayStart = Time.time;
        }
    }

    void UpdateTarget ()
    {
        if(automatic)
        {
            if(Time.time - delayStart > delayTime)
            {
                nextPlatform();
            }
        }
    }

    public void nextPlatform() 
    {
        pointNumber++;

        if(pointNumber >= points.Length)
        {
            pointNumber = 0;
        }
        currentTarget = points[pointNumber];
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) 
    {
        other.transform.parent = transform;
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit (Collider other) 
    {
        other.transform.parent = null;
    }
}
```

I stole this from the unity fps microgame

> Loadscene:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SwitchScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Play(string Scenename) {  
        SceneManager.LoadScene(Scenename);  
    } 

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Level of select");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty sure since I don't have a view of your scene setup (starting point, targets...) but after reading your code, there is a point that you might want to look at. Under

```
void UpdateTarget ()
{
    if(automatic)
    {
        if(Time.time - delayStart > delayTime)
        {
            nextPlatform();
        }
    }
}
```

`Time.time` is eslapsed time from the beginning of the application start, so the calculation here will have different outputs between starting from menu scene versus starting from level scene. You might want to use `Time.timeSinceLevelLoad` instead.(https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeSinceLevelLoad.html)

`Time.timeSinceLevelLoad` only work for this case if you loading scene as non-additive. With additive loading, you'll need a custom implementation to track the proper start time.

Comment: Could you link an article or video about the custom implementation? I'm new to unity. (I did try Time.timeSinceLevelLoad and it didn't work)